What happened to the demon from the Garden?
In the first episode of Season 4, Wynonna, Waverly, and Doc encounter a demon in the Garden that can change shape and appears to have been kept prisoner by regular offerings of blood. She identifies herself as "Eve," although whether this means that she is actually the Biblical Eve is unclear. In any case, despite the relatively modest nature of the powers demonstrated by Eve, she seems like a high-value prisoner:  the Garden appears to be dedicated to  keeping her captive, it is implied that Bulshar might have been seeking to free her, and she swore revenge on humanity. During their confrontation, Eve is pushed through a portal, and is not seen for the remainder of the season, with a motley array of Black Badge agents, Clantons, angels, and so forth constituting the remaining enemies. However, we have seen that the portals lead to other places, including (or  perhaps exclusively?) locations on Earth.
The special aired in 2024 also does not mention her, focusing instead on an antagonist with a personal vendetta, although it seems to allude to a possible continuation of the series.
In any case, wherever she ended up, it seems fair to say that Eve would not have abandoned her single-minded focus on revenge. So, what happened to her?
